# How to keep the original index when using the predict function of a skicit-learn model

Tags: scikit-learn

How can I keep an index of a dataset by passing it through the predict function of a sklearn model?

I use this code in Jupyter Notebook, but the output file doesn't keep the original index in `X_prod`.

```
clf_Naive = joblib.load('Name.pkl')
predNaive = clf_Naive.predict(X_prod)
predNaiveProba = clf_Naive.predict_proba(X_prod)
pred = pd.DataFrame(data=predNaive)
pred.to_csv('Pred_Naive.csv', sep=';',header=False, index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem might be in `joblib.load()` as load takes 2 params

1.filename

2.mode in which you want too read your file

Check out this for more detail
[[https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.load.html1]](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.load.html)

Comment: ** Thanks @Vibhav, I was review but this link talk to compress method in job lib but not about the predict function. I found another solution and i trait make the same with the function predict, but don't work and I lose the index**

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_prod_cat1[:] = sc_X.fit_transform(X_prod_cat1.values)

import joblib
clf_Naive = joblib.load('Naive5050.pkl')
predNaive[:] = clf_Naive.predict(X_prod_cat1[:].values)

pred = pd.DataFrame(data=predNaive[:])  
pred.to_csv('Pred_Naive.csv', sep=';',header=False, index=True)